# Is there a way to handle IOS notification action button click when app is killed?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I use react-native-firebase to manage push notifications on IOS. I have buttons in notification and want to execute some server request when user click one of them. Everything works when app is foreground or background. 
The app execute the code in `onNotificationOpened` listener.

I use `react-native-background-task` and `react-native-queue` to handle when user click on button in notification when app is background.

When app is killed/terminated, the notification show actions button that I added to notification categories but code defined in `onNotificationOpened` listener not executing.

I except that application send server request if it's in killed/terminated state too.

Any suggest ?